# Git show file in target branch in JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I want to show to file content of a target branch in JGit without checking out that branch. For example, showing the content of `README.md` of `master` branch while the current branch is `iss1`. The equivalent Git command should be:

```
myProj (iss1) $ git show master:README.md
Hello world!
```

How can I do it using JGit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993634/how-do-i-do-git-show-sha1file-using-jgit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no direct equivalent to `git show` in JGit, it provides API to implement what the command does yourself.

If all you have is the ref to a branch, then you first need to resolve the tree id of its head commit. Luckily, `Repository::resolve` accepts an expression that will return the necessary tree id:

```java
ObjectId treeId = repository.resolve("refs/heads/master^{tree}");
```

Given the tree id, you can use a `TreeWalk` to obtain the blob id that holds the contents of the desired file.

```java
TreeWalk treeWalk = TreeWalk.forPath(git.getRepository(), "README.md", treeId);
ObjectId blobId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
```

The `forPath` factory method creates a `TreeWalk` and positions it at the path that was given in the second argument.

With the blob id in turn, you can finally load the contents from Git's object database.

```java
ObjectReader objectReader = repository.newObjectReader();
ObjectLoader objectLoader = objectReader.open(blobId);
byte[] bytes = objectLoader.getBytes();
objectReader.close();
```

The complete source code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/rherrmann/0c682ea327862cb6847704acf90b1d5d

For more details about the inner workings of the Git object database, you may want to read [Explore Git Internals with the JGit API](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals).